# Asus UX32VD on 12.10 stopped working after upgrade to kernel 3.5.0-19-generic

Tags: 12.10, kernel, asus

I own an Asus UX32VD. I managed to install 12.10 without any problems following the advices on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime). Everything worked as expected, even many of the Fn keys, excluding F5 and F6.

The problem came after upgrading the kernel to 3.5.0-19 and onwards (as suggested by ubuntu update manager) that WMI stopped to work. When executing lsmod I can see far less modules loaded than when I boot with a working kernel and loading those modules by hand does not work. Actually every fn key behaves as if I was pressing fn+f4 (this after loading the modules by hand).

Is there anything I can do to make this work? 
Shouldn't I be using 12.10 with this hardware?

Right now the solution I have is to manually boot with kernel 3.5.0-18 that seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... solved. The modules directory /lib/modules/ was not present at boot time. Only some of the kernels had the directory present.

Making the directory available at boot time solved the problem.